# Filter elements of a list in Python

Tags: python, list, filter, list-comprehension

I would like to filter the elements of a given list.
I have an integer and I would like to only keep the numbers in a list which all characters are less than that number. (Now it is 5). I can write a longer code for this, but I would like to have a 1 line code using `filter()` .

I only got this far:

```
def fil(l):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x<5, [int(s) for i in l for s in str(i)]))
```

for `l = [1,2,4,8,12]` it should give back:

```
[1, 2, 4, 12]
```

But it returns this:

```
[1, 2, 4, 1, 2]
```

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: You are passing it as a string. In your list comprehension it goes through '12' as int(1) and then int(2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using `filter` This might help :

```py
l = [1,2,4,8,12]
results = [item for item in l if all(int(x) < 5 for x in str(item))]
```

If you want necessarily use filter and your function `fil` then you have :

```py
def fil(l):
    return list(filter(lambda item: all(int(x) < 5 for x in str(item)), l))
```